# How can I update only the lodash package a child dependent(required dependency package for babel/core) from lodash@4.17.19 to v4.17.21

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, lodash, angular-localize

Recently `lodash` package reported a security vulnerability issue on the github page. You can find details here. https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5083.

```
This latest version of lodash has security vulnerability of Command Injection (CVE-2021-23337).
https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-23337
https://snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-LODASH-1040724

All versions of package lodash; all versions of package org.fujion.webjars:lodash are vulnerable to Command Injection via template.
```

They have resolved the issue and its fix is present in the lodash v4.17.21.
I am using the Angular 10 version. I am not using lodash directly but, One of the angular package that is `@angular/localize@10.0.7` internally uses uses `@babel/core@7.8.3` and this babel internally uses `lodash@4.17.19`.

Angular people will update the version number in their latest release and currently, I don't want to upgrade to the latest version of angular. Therefore, my question is how can I update only the lodash package, a child dependent(required dependency package for babel/core) from lodash@4.17.19 to v4.17.21 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm update lodash` did the trick for me.

```
$ npm -v
7.6.0
$ npm ls lodash  
temp@1.0.0 /Users/trott/temp
└─┬ @angular/localize@10.2.4
  └─┬ @babel/core@7.8.3
    ├─┬ @babel/traverse@7.13.0
    │ └── lodash@4.17.19 deduped
    ├─┬ @babel/types@7.13.0
    │ └── lodash@4.17.19 deduped
    └── lodash@4.17.19

$ npm update lodash

changed 1 package, and audited 99 packages in 1s

6 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npm ls lodash
temp@1.0.0 /Users/trott/temp
└─┬ @angular/localize@10.2.4
  └─┬ @babel/core@7.8.3
    ├─┬ @babel/traverse@7.13.0
    │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
    ├─┬ @babel/types@7.13.0
    │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
    └── lodash@4.17.21

$
```

This isn't *exactly* what you asked for because it updates to the latest `lodash` that satisfies the requirements of your dependencies, rather than the specific version `4.17.21`. It just so happens that (at the time of this writing), that latest version for `@angular/localize` is `4.17.21`. If you genuinely need a specific version that isn't the latest that satisfies your dependencies, read on.

Let's say, hypothetically, you wanted to update to `4.17.20`. You might try `npm update lodash@4.17.20`. Alas, that doesn't work. The command runs fine, but doesn't update anything. In that case, you'd have to `npm install lodash@4.17.20` first. That will update all your dependencies as well (assuming `4.17.20` satisfies their requirements). Then `npm uninstall lodash@4.17.20` to remove it from your direct dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Trott for your answer. I have tried this approach and it indeed downloaded the latest package version of the lodash that is 4.17.21. But, what really bugs me is the lodash version mentioned in requires of babel/core still shows the package version as 4.17.19 in package.lock.json. Is it going to be just a version as ^4.17.19 number but the js files will be of 4.17.21. Why didn't get updated too ?

Comment: Hmmm...When I do `npm ls` above, it shows lodash 4.17.21 for everything, including the `babel/core` dependency. The only reason I can think for `bable/core` to not have its dependency updated is if there is some *other* dependency that requires lodash at 4.17.19 and not 4.17.21. Which would seem to mean there is a dependency that locks lodash at exactly 4.17.19. What is the output of `npm ls lodash` after you do the update? And what version of `npm` are you running?

Comment: well the "npm ls lodash" shows the packages updated with the latest version that is 4.17.21. The version I am running npm is 6.14.6

Comment: When you say the `package-lock.json` is showing `lodash` 4.17.19 for `babel/core`, are you seeing something like this? `"lodash": "^4.17.19"` Or are you seeing `"version": "4.17.19"` somewhere?

Comment: It is "lodash": "^4.17.19"

Comment: Ah, OK, then that's not the installed version. That's the version required by the package. The leading `^` means "any 4.x version that is 4.17.19 or higher".

Comment: That means, the Babel/Core is actually using the 4.17.21 and not 4.17.19. So, now if anyone other than me, If they do npm install, they will have 4.17.21(latest version).  If this is correct could you please provide any official  article to support this.

Comment: Yes, versions specified in your `package-lock.json` will be respected when other developers install the package. (If you publish your app/package to a repository like `npm`, the mechanism is different. If you want to gaurantee 4.17.21 and not 4.17.22 or 4.18.0 when those exist, you'll want to publish an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file with your package.)

Comment: Documentation of the meaning of `^`:  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004. Documentation of the fact that `package-lock.json` insures identical versions across developers: first bullet point at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#description.